# Casting TIMESTAMP Data type into DATE only

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I have a table which includes a Date column and a Time column. Both columns have TIMESTAMP data type by default, but I'd like to change the data type of both the date and time columns to match the format yyyy-mm-dd and hh:mm:ss, respectively, to only display the date in Date column and only the time in Time column.

I've used cast() to change the Date column to DATE datatype as follows:

```
cast(occ.OCCURRENCEDATE as DATE)
```

However, I cannot do the same for the Time column as there is no specific TIME datatype. I've tried passing more parameters to TIMESTAMP datatype to only store the time value, but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be highly appreciated. Solution can be in sql or python, thanks!

Edit: Just to clarify, the Date and Time fields are being used for a dashboard. Both fields only come with their respective information, ie. date value for Date column and time value for Time column. So, it's important that both fields only display the specific information, barring the auto-assigned values if they are TIMESTAMP data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [INTERVAL](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/interval-type.html) type to store time, this will be convenient for further processing.

```
SELECT ts as timestamp,
       cast(ts as date) as date,
       ts - cast(ts as date) as time
  FROM (SELECT current_timestamp() as ts);

+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
|timestamp              |date      |time                              |
+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
|2023-02-01 19:41:24.068|2023-02-01|19 hours 41 minutes 24.068 seconds|
+-----------------------+----------+----------------------------------+

root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- date: date (nullable = false)
 |-- time: interval (nullable = false)
```

Or if you only care about specific formatting into a string just use [date_format](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format.html) function.

```
SELECT ts as timestamp,
       date_format(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date,
       date_format(ts, 'HH:mm:ss') as time
  FROM (SELECT current_timestamp() as ts);

+-----------------------+----------+--------+
|timestamp              |date      |time    |
+-----------------------+----------+--------+
|2023-02-03 14:42:17.845|2023-02-03|14:42:17|
+-----------------------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: I tried that, but the output is in a different format.
https://imgur.com/a/Qnk4c0A

Should I just convert it to a string using the datetime library?

Comment: I thought you'd want to keep it proper data type to process later, but if all you want is a string, then all you need is one function (date_format) - I edited my answer to show it.

Comment: Hi, thank you Kombajn. This was extremely helpful and quite simple to understand. I'll also experiment with the initial datatype preservation you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to get the time information as string:

```
select 
transform(
  array(current_timestamp())
  , ts -> concat_ws(':'
  , transform(
    array(hour(ts), minute(ts), second(ts)), hms -> right('0'|| hms, 2)
    )))[0] time
```